# How to add external page to file jsp?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I downloaded my project from `start.spring.io` and the folder structure is as it appears in the picture and I can not add `special-title.html` page to `home.jsp` page.

I use the following commands for integration.

`<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/special-title.html"></jsp:include>`

`<jsp:include page="../WEB-INF/jsp/special-title.html"></jsp:include>`

`<jsp:include page="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/WEB-INF/jsp/special-title.html"></jsp:include>`

However, I could not run these commands. Where am I making a mistake?

[Picture of project folder structure](https://i.imgur.com/If7U3By.png)

**POM.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**application.properties**

```
server.port=7070
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

**DemoController.java**

```
package com.example.demo.controller;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
@Controller
public class DemoController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String showHomePage() {
        return "home";
    }

}
```

**home.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>


<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/special-title.html"></jsp:include>

<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

**special-title.html**

```
<h2>SPECIAL TITLE</h2>
```

**Testing Url**

```
http://localhost:7070/home
```

Comment: You didn't give any response!

Answer (score 0):

First move your `special-title.html` from `WEB-INF` to `templates` folder which is under `resources`.

Then in jsp file try adding line `<%@ include file="resources/templates/special-title.html"%>` instead of `<jsp:include page="/WEB-INF/jsp/special-title.html"></jsp:include>`

To run html as jsp you can do one thing. Write a `web.xml` inside `WEB-INF` like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
<jsp-config>
    <jsp-property-group>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
</web-app>
```

Comment: I've tried the method you're saying but it still not working. And I get this error message.
`Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Feb 03 14:41:58 EET 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
/WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [10], column: [1]) File [resources/templates/special-title.html] not found
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/jsp/home.jsp (line: [10], column: [1]) File [resources/templates/special-title.html] not found`

Comment: @EG Why do you want to html and jsp at the same time ? Why don't you choose one ?

Comment: @EG, check my current answer !